# Installing Nlog Config into Eventlog with InstallNlogConfig

Tags: c#, .net, logging, nlog

I'm trying to write a log with Nlog into Eventlog, this a example of my Nlog.config

```
<target xsi:type="EventLog" 
    name="eventlog"
    layout="${message}"
    log="Application" 
    source="MyAppName"  />
```

When executing `InstallNlogConfig` with Administrator rigths this show this error:

> NLog.NLogConfigurationException: Error during initialization of
>   EventLog Target[eventlog] - System.IO.IOException: The network path
>   was not found.
>
> en Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.Win32ErrorStatic(Int32 errorCode,
>   String str)    en
>   Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive hKey,
>   String machineName, RegistryView view)    en
>   System.Diagnostics.EventLog.GetEventLogRegKey(String machine, Boolean
>   writable)    en
>   System.Diagnostics.EventLog.FindSourceRegistration(String source,
>   String machineName, Boolean readOnly, Boolean wantToCreate)    en
>   System.Diagnostics.EventLog._InternalLogNameFromSourceName(String
>   source, String machineName)    en
>   System.Diagnostics.EventLog.LogNameFromSourceName(String source,
>   String machineName)    en
>   NLog.Targets.EventLogTarget.InitializeTarget() en
>   c:\NLogBuild\src\NLog\Targets\EventLogTarget.cs:línea 175    en
>   NLog.Targets.Target.Initialize(LoggingConfiguration configuration) en
>   c:\NLogBuild\src\NLog\Targets\Target.cs:línea 288. 2013-06-10
>   12:21:05.0708 Info Shutting down logging... 2013-06-10 12:21:05.0708
>   Info Logger has been shut down.

Comment: You've misspelled the machine name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading into Nlog, Eventlog target.

this post http://berryware.wordpress.com/2009/11/06/nlog-and-windows-event-log-bug/ explain with more details what that happening 
I didn’t have machineName defined.  After all, the documentation stated that machineName defaults to the local machine anyway, so why set it to anything?  Well… because if you don’t then a boolean member var called _operational stays “false” and it needs to be set to “true”

https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/EventLog-target

machineName - Name of the machine on which Event Log service is running. Default: .

To easy Fix:

```
<target  name="eventlog"  xsi:type="EventLog"  layout="${longdate}|${level}|${message}"  log="Application"  source="My Source"  machineName="." />
```

Comment: This should have been fixed in v2.0.1 of NLog